# Does Ant Haul let you drag more stuff too?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

I was reading the spell [ant haul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul) and at first glace it seems very straight forward.

> The target's carrying capacity triples. This does not affect the creature's actual Strength in any way, merely the amount of material it can carry while benefiting from this spell. It also has no effect on encumbrance due to armor. If the creature wears armor it still takes the normal penalties for doing so regardless of how much weight the spell allows it to carry.

Then the following line stood out to me and made me wonder if it only applies to things you are carrying, or if it also applies to the other methods such as dragging.

> This does not affect the creature's actual Strength in any way, merely the amount of material it can **carry** while benefiting from this spell.

So, does the spell affect all forms of carrying capacity or specifically what you can carry?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, [Ant Haul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul) increases the amount that a character can drag.

Under the *Lifting and Dragging* section of [Carrying Capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity):

> A character can lift as much as his maximum load over his head. ...
>
> A character can lift as much as double his maximum load off the ground, but he or she can only stagger around with it. ...
>
> A character can generally push or drag along the ground as much as five times his maximum load. ...

Note that the maximum load is determined by referencing the [Carrying Capacity Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity#TOC-Table-Carrying-Capacity).

Thus, the amount that a creature can lift over their head, lift off of the ground, or drag along the ground is calculated based on carrying capacity.

Since [Ant Haul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul) directly affects carrying capacity, the derived values must be similarly modified.

Comment: While I agree that it totally *should*, why *must* this general rule override the specificity of *ant haul*?

Comment: (Disclaimer - not a Pathfinder player) I don't read that it overrides specificity. A spell that increased your running speed would also increase your (derived) sprinting speed. If X=2Y, then anything that increases X will also increase Y.

Comment: The specificity of Ant Haul simply prevents players from trying to convince their GMs that they should reverse-engineer their strength and get crazy bonuses on attack, damage, grapple, etc.. Dragging, however, is an aspect of Carrying Capacity, so it would get modified.